# Fill empty space in string

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have a string that contains many lines such as:

```
$str = 'A    1   AAA
                BBB
            2   CCC
                DDD
        B   1   EEE
                FFF
        C   1   GGG
                HHH';
```

I want to fill empty space like this:

```
A   1   AAA
A   1   BBB
A   2   CCC
A   2   DDD
B   1   EEE
B   1   FFF
C   1   GGG
C   1   HHH
```

How can I do it with php ?

My Code: https://eval.in/522676

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) and [branch reset](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) regex to maintain group index.

```
$re = '/^\h*(?|(\S+)\h+(\S+)\h+(\S+)|()(\S+)\h+(\S+)|()()(\S+))\s*$/m';
```

[See explanation on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zG9bY6/1); pad empty values in col 1 & 2 with last non-empty value above.

```
$str = preg_replace_callback($re, function($m) use (&$prev)
{
 // set empty values if previous not empty
 if($m[1]==="" && $prev[1] !== "") $m[1] = $prev[1];
 if($m[2]==="" && $prev[2] !== "") $m[2] = $prev[2];

 // store previous value
 if($m[1]!=="") $prev[1] = $m[1];
 if($m[2]!=="") $prev[2] = $m[2];

 // newly formatted
 return $m[1] . "   " . $m[2] . "   " . $m[3];
}, $str);
```

[Demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/522672)